# "Fb.ui send dialog" returns error

Tags: facebook, dialog, send, fb.ui

I have a strange issue with the dialog.
Here is a simple code, that I'm using in my project:

```
        FB.ui({
            app_id: 'MY_APP_ID',
            method: 'send',
            name: 'Test',
            link: 'MY_APP_LINK',
            display: 'iframe'
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

And after dialog opened, I got a common error, which nothing describes:

Here it is in original language:
"Обнаружена ошибка в APP_NAME. Пожалуйста, попробуйте ещё раз позже."
And I think in english it should sound like:
"An error occurred in APP_NAME. Please, try again later."

Could anybody help me, and explain why it is happens, please? I've read documentation at least three times, and didn't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your domain settings for your app – calling dialogs from a page not allowed for the app is a common cause for this kind of error.

Comment: If that’s not the case, set the optional dialog parameter show_error to true, that should give additional info.

Comment: Thank you, I've checked and there is a proper domain, but after I added show_error, I've got error 102: "Session key invalid or no longer valid"

Comment: Also I read about this error on stackoverflow, but I'm sure, that I'm use the right api-key|app-id

Answer (score 1):

You have to give it a valid link - try setting my link to "http://www.google.com".

Answer (score 1):

What kind of device are you using?

In case you are doing this on a tablet/phone, the "send" dialogue doesn't currently support those devices and will result in an error.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

From their doc:

> You should specify a URL, and you can pre-populate a user in the ‘to’
>   field. The Send Dialog does not require any extended permissions. This
>   Dialog is currently not supported on mobile devices.